# Change the size of cylinder/rope in realtime (GameLogic)

Tags: game-engine, objects

I want a cylinder or other object to change size when the main object changes its position. The cylinder needs to be a line that connects two points. All of this need to be able to change in the game logic as the main object that moves is controlled by a joystick.

The Stretch To would work great if I could get the end bones to connect/parent to the end point objects. I have a cylinder created with bones and Stretch To but it does not work in game logic.

Answer (score 1):

Created two "endpoint" objects that move in gamelogic mode. Then grab their center location do some geometry and python code changes the cylinder (rope). only used one endpoint in the code below as the other endpoint was origin (0, 0, 0). Also note that this only watches one plane (x and z axis).

```
#get endpoint center location
boom_endpoint = boom_point.worldPosition

#get distance between endpoints    
y_pow = (boom_endpoint[2])**2
x_pow = (boom_endpoint[0])**2
rope_distance = math.sqrt(x_pow + y_pow)

#scale value for axis that need to be stretched 
new_scale = rope_distance/2

#angle between endpoints to rotate the rope
angle = math.asin(boom_endpoint[2]/rope_distance)             
rope.localOrientation = rope.localOrientation * mathutils.Vector((math.radians(0), angle, math.radians(0))) 
#apply scale and location changes
rope.localScale = mathutils.Vector((1, 1, new_scale))
rope.worldPosition = mathutils.Vector(((boom_endpoint[0]+0)/2, 0, (boom_endpoint[2]+0)/2))
```